# Nested Map issue: While clearing the inner map, the outside Map value is also clearing

Tags: java, hashmap

Here I am collecting some data in the inner map and along with User ID, it putting to the Outer Map. Then Inner Map is clearing and filling another set of data and looping the same for number of users.
The issue is While clearing the InnerMap, the Value put in the outer map is also clearing. I think I'm doing some mistake. Kindly advice.

```
HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>();
            HashMap<Integer, HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>> outerMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>>();
            List<MDocumentNumber> docNumbers = new Query(getCtx(), MDocumentNumber.Table_Name, "IsActive = 'Y'", get_TrxName())
                                                .setOrderBy("CreatedBy").list();        
            int createdBy = 0;
            int nextUser = 0; 
            for (MDocumentNumber docNumber : docNumbers) 
            {   
                createdBy = docNumber.getCreatedBy();           
                MAttachment attachment = new MAttachment(getCtx(), MDocumentNumber.Table_ID, docNumber.get_ID(), get_TrxName());
                int attchmentCount = attachment.getEntryCount();
                int versionCount = docNumber.getVersionCount().intValue();
                if(versionCount > 0 && attchmentCount < versionCount)
                {
                    if(nextUser != 0 && nextUser != createdBy)
                    {
                        outerMap.put(nextUser, innerMap); // for a new user, put the inner map data to Outer Map
                        innerMap.clear();               // Here while clearing the inner map, the outer map value is also clearing  
                    }
                    innerMap.put(docNumber, (attchmentCount-versionCount));
                    nextUser = createdBy;
                }           
            }   
            outerMap.put(createdBy, innerMap);
```

Comment: you only ever have 1 `innerMap` instance - maybe you want to create a new `innerMap` instance for every entry that you add to `outerMap`?

Comment: @TmTron Thanks, Meaning I have to create `innerMap = new HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>();` inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks @TmTron. Its working well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tm Tron. The comment is working well. Im posting here the change for my preceders :

```
HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>> outerMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>>();
        List<MDocumentNumber> docNumbers = new Query(getCtx(), MDocumentNumber.Table_Name, "IsActive = 'Y'", get_TrxName())
                                            .setOrderBy("CreatedBy").list();        
        int createdBy = 0;
        int nextUser = 0; 
        for (MDocumentNumber docNumber : docNumbers) 
        {   
            createdBy = docNumber.getCreatedBy();           
            MAttachment attachment = new MAttachment(getCtx(), MDocumentNumber.Table_ID, docNumber.get_ID(), get_TrxName());
            int attchmentCount = attachment.getEntryCount();
            int versionCount = docNumber.getVersionCount().intValue();
            if(versionCount > 0 && attchmentCount < versionCount)
            {
                if(nextUser != 0 && nextUser != createdBy)
                {
                    outerMap.put(nextUser, innerMap); // for a new user, put the inner map data to Outer Map
                    //innerMap.clear();             // Here while clearing the inner map, the outer map value is also clearing
                    innerMap = new HashMap<MDocumentNumber, Integer>();
                }
                innerMap.put(docNumber, (attchmentCount-versionCount));
                nextUser = createdBy;
            }           
        }   
        outerMap.put(createdBy, innerMap);
```